# Phalclon route invo/index not found on server

Tags: php, url-routing, phalcon

I followed the tutorial at http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-invo.html.
Everything wokrs fine but the "home" link, that points to localhost/invo/index/index/
will give an error stating file not found or what ever. Index is defined as it should be in the project and the funny thing is that if I type localhost/invo/foo/bar/(does not exist) I recive the message stating that I am not allowed to watch said module.

Am I missing something in the tutorial? Am I missing something? Or is this an apache problem? I get the same error when tying in /index in tutorial 1 aswell. So it seen that there is a bit problem just with the word "index".

Im running debian 7 by the way if thats somewhat relevant.

Comment: can you add your error exactly as it shown to you

Comment: http://localhost:1080/invo/about/index - works fine
http://localhost:1080/invo/nothing/there - gives a routing error, route not there or user not authorized. Correct behavior.
http://localhost:1080/invo/index/index - 404 - Not Found
The requested URL /invo/public/index/index was not found on this server. The word index appears to have some "special power" as it does not appear to be picked up by the routing in the framework at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is may not the full solution but apparently you have the same issue as the guy here http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1393/indexcontroller-cause-unmanaged-404-error-on-apache-w-mod-rewrit

You may are right about the index for being special word as it is the default index page name, so you can avoid naming the controller as `IndexController` you can use something like `HomeController`.

**Hint:** try to clone the source code from git to ensure that you get the correct code with the correct `.htaccss` you may already did that.

```
git clone https://github.com/phalcon/invo.git
```

Comment: As suggested in the thread you linked the problem was with the MultiViews option in the apache settings. Thank you very much for your help.